# Convert string to non-string input for function

Tags: r, naming

How can I store a string (e.g., the column range `"cyl:drat, vs:gear"`) so that I can use it in a function where it should *not* be interpreted as character string?

---

For example, I would like to execute the following command:

```
subset(mtcars, select=c(disp:drat, vs:gear))
```

But assign the content for `select` to a variable `x`:

```
x <- as.name("cyl:drat, vs:gear")
subset(mtcars, select=x)
#Error in x[j] : invalid subscript type 'symbol'

library(rlang)
x <- quo(!! sym("cyl:drat, vs:gear"))
subset(mtcars, select=x)
#Error in x[j] : invalid subscript type 'language'

x <- parse_expr("cyl:drat, vs:gear")
subset(mtcars, select=x)
#Error in x[j] : invalid subscript type 'language'
```

Assigning `x <-"cyl"` works, but `x <-"cyl:drat"` similarly fails.

---

Hints as to what format `x` should have would already be a welcome start.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You missed the `c()` in your expression, and you also need to `eval` your expressions inside `subset`:

```
library(rlang)

x <- parse_expr("c(cyl:drat, vs:gear)")
subset(mtcars, select=eval(x))
```

`parse_expr` is equivalent to `parse` in base R:

```
x2 = parse(text="c(cyl:drat, vs:gear)")
subset(mtcars, select=eval(x2))
```

You can also use `parse_expr` or `parse_exprs` alongside `select` from `dplyr`, which is where it was intended to be used:

```
library(dplyr)

select(mtcars, !! x)
```

or for splicing a list of expressions:

```
y = parse_exprs("cyl:drat; vs:gear")
select(mtcars, !!! y)
```